# tsql utility cannot display full precision of FLOAT in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, floating-point, ssms, precision

I run the `tsql` freeTDS utility on linux to query SQL Server.

There is number stored as `FLOAT` type, like 7.73128372482378837.

When I query this column in `tsql`, it only shows the first two decimals: 7.73, which is similar to what you would see in SSMS UI. The only way I have found to actually see the actual value of my `FLOAT` columns is to "EDIT first 200 rows" in SSMS, which is not quite what I want.

How can I enable `tsql` or `osql` full precision output capability?

Comment: You should stop using `isql` or `osql` on Windows - both are long deprecated. Use `sqlcmd` instead

Comment: I said I used it on linux. Just curious, you mean tsql has been deprecated as well?

Comment: you mention `osql` in your question - I assumed you mean the `osql` command line utility on Windows - **this** (and it's even older cousin, `isql`) - has been deprecated **for many years now** - that's **all** I'm saying .....